# Error 403 Forbidden, When Logged in for almost 5 Minutes in Laravel App

Tags: laravel

I recently uploaded my laravel project to production server through git. Now Every time I browse my website, it works fine but when I logged in then after 4,5 minutes I start seeing error 403 Forbidden (You don't have permission to access / on this server.)

Then I clear the site's cookies from browser and it works fine again.

What could be the reason ? how can I fix this permanently ? I tried searching on internet and found something which is saying that it has something to do with login session. But I could not figured out what it is. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Look's like you need to change the default value for the session tokens lifetime in `config/session.php`

there should be a part like this:

```
'lifetime' => 120,
```

Hope it helps o/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for helping. I figured out that the problem was with my user's permission. Which I fixed and its working good.Thanks

Comment: can you please share? i am experiencing the same issue